# Slicing R arrays by index pair

Tags: arrays, r, slice

I have an array in R with 3 columns that looks like:

```
>x
[,1]     [,2] [,3]
V1 7.803550 0.000000    0
V2 7.842899 0.000000    0
V3 7.310273 0.000000    0
V4 7.230438 0.000000    0
V5 6.582147 1.097024    0
V6 9.364152 0.000000    0
```

For my array slice, I want different columns from each row, so that the indices of what I want are:

```
rows<-1:6
cols<-c(1,1,1,2,3,1)
```

When I try to get the appropriate array slice in R, instead of getting a vector with the appropriate values,

```
> t
      V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6 
7.803550 7.842899 7.310273 0.000000 0.000000 9.364152
```

I get a 6x6 matrix of output where a given column is printed out for all selected rows

```
> t
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]     [,6]
V1 7.803550 7.803550 7.803550 0.000000    0 7.803550
V2 7.842899 7.842899 7.842899 0.000000    0 7.842899
V3 7.310273 7.310273 7.310273 0.000000    0 7.310273
V4 7.230438 7.230438 7.230438 0.000000    0 7.230438
V5 6.582147 6.582147 6.582147 1.097024    0 6.582147
V6 9.364152 9.364152 9.364152 0.000000    0 9.364152
```

How can I get my desired index pairs in a vector without a for loop?

Per David's suggestion, the code I was hoping would work would be

```
t<-x[rows,cols]
```

Comment: You should show the line when you calculate `t` if you're showing the results of it (I'm guessing `t = x[rows, cols]`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
x[cbind(rows, cols)]
```

Read in ?"[" why this should work. (I will lay odds it's faster than Robinson's sapply strategy.)

Comment: Thanks DWin!  That worked perfectly and looks really clean too

Answer (score 1):

Probably can't do better than

```
sapply(1:length(rows), function(i) x[rows[i], cols[i]])
```

Comment: @Mitch: great- but you should select DWin's answer, which is better (learn something new every day!)

Comment: There is no right, wrong or better. There'y only apply family. :P

Comment: Very generous of you David.  Your sapply trick will help me quite a bit though as well!

Comment: The sapply trick is really a for-loop that builds its own environment. It's helpful in migrating from SAS-think to R-mode.